# Search only children of a protractor webElementFinder using CSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a protractor webElementFinder `testElement`. I want to match only its  `div` children (NOT grandchildren or any other further descendants) and thus `testElement.find('div')` will not work as it will find all descendant divs.

If protractor worked like jQuery (which would make sense since Angular is smart enough to use jQuery if its present and protractor is built with Angular in mind), I would just do `testElement.find(' > div')` which would work despite the `find` argument not being a valid CSS selector by itself; however because protractor just uses built in Element functions, that CSS selector is not valid by itself, and protractor throws an error.

I could go this route [Angular JS, Protractor locator, get direct children of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428821/angular-js-protractor-locator-get-direct-children-of-element) since xpath natively lets you look at children, but I'd much rather use CSS than xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct and easy way to have a direct parent-child locator from the current element. A common way to solve it is to use the `./` XPath expression, but there is also this "hack" that uses [`locator()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.locator):

```
testElement.$(testElement.locator().value + ' > div');
```

Comment: Selecting this as the answer since it avoids restating the selector (i.e. it follows DRY).

Comment: Great idea, but in my case `.locator().value` returns an xpath, not a css.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
$('testElement > div')
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on a few things:

1. if testElement is an ElementFinder (`const testelement = element(by.css('.some-selector'))`), then you can do `testelement.all(by.css('div'))`. Be aware of the `all`, because you are talking about **chrildren**, you will find all *children* with all. It will return an *ElementArrayFinder*, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all)
2. if testElement is a selector (`const foo = '.testElement'`), then you can do `$$('.testElement > div')`. This will return all the  It will return an *ElementArrayFinder*, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$)

I hope you can add the selector of `testElement` to the css selector with the `>`, the advantage you will get from this is that you will get all elements that are a direct children of the `testElement`-selector